# About sandwich theorem

Tags: limits

As we know when we have $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$, and if $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ have the same limit $L$ at $x=c$ then $g(x)$ also have limit $L$ at $x=c$.

Can we say that if limit of $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ at $x=c$ doesn't exist then also limit $g(x)$  doesn't exist ?

If this was not correct then any counter example?

Comment: Counter example let g (x)=0. f (x)=-1+sin (1/(x-c)). h (x)=1+sin (1/(x-c)).

Comment: f and g can oscillate below and above a convergent g (x).

Comment: Or even simpler f (x)-> -infinity while h (x)-> + infinity.

Comment: However if f and h both tend to positive or negative infinity then, yes, so does g (x).

Comment: @fleablood What is nature of c ie  either positive or negative..

Comment: I don't know.  c was *your* variable.  It doesn't matter.  x->c.  It doesn't matter what c is. I just wanted something that oscillate and had no limit.  sin x oscilates without limit as x goes to infinity.  So I wanted f (x) =sin y where y-> infinity as x-> c.  So I did sin (1/x-c).  That oscilates without limit between -1 and 1.  I subtracted 1 to get it below 0.

Comment: just a side note: the expression $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ is not well-defined because we dont know for what values of $x$ holds.

Comment: a second point: a limit is not reached at any point. The definition of limit excludes the point where $x$ is approaching.

Comment: Masacroso.  I don't understand what you mean by the expression not being well defined.  The statement is true if it holds for all x in the domain.  Admittedly my counter examples were undefined at x=c but that's not very relevent and/or easy to fix.

Comment: I also agree with fleablood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter example.  Let $f (x)\le 0$ but have no limit as $x\rightarrow c $. $h (x)\ge 0$ but have no limit. While $g (x)=0$ has limit of $0$

There are many examples.  Let $f (x)= 0$ if $x $ is irrational and $f (x)=-1 $ if x is rational. Or if you want something continuous $f (x)=-|\frac 1{x-c}|$.  Or if you want something bounded chose something that oscilates:$f (x) =\sin (\frac 1 {x-c}) - 1$.

$g (x) $ needn't be constant.  It could be any function with a limit while $f $ and $h$ could be any larger and lesser function without limits.

Example: $g (x)=x $ (which has a limit of $c $. And $f (x)= x - \sin (\frac {1}{x-c}) $ and $h (x)=x + |\frac 1 {x-c}|$